# Trying to install net-snmp in linux throws error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, net-snmp

I am trying to install net-snmp in linux using the following command.

```
yum install net-snmp net-snmp-utils
```

but this command is throwing the following error:

> file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.61-1.el7.x86_64

What does this mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you installed `mysql-community-libs-compat` package.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I solved the issue by installing MySQL-server-5.7